# Python Jupyter Notebook can not open file, probably output too large

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I work with big .csv files in python and I probably had too many prints during the data processing. Now I can not open the file (345 MB) any more. I get the error code "SBOX_FATAL_MEMORY_EXCEEDED" after a few seconds. Is there a way to delete the ouput somehow or a different workaround? It would be enough for me to copy my existing code but it breaks down that quickly that I can not even do this.
Tell me if you need additional information.

Thanks

Comment: Add More Details, Please.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use nbconvert, run this code in a shell or command prompt

you may need to install with pip, but I believe it is included with jupyter

```
jupyter nbconvert my_input_notebook.ipynb --to notebook --ClearOutputPreprocessor.enabled=True --output my_output_notebook
```

[source](https://mindtrove.info/jupyter-tidbit-clear-outputs/)

Answer (score 0):

If you donot want to delete all the existing outputs but only delete the one which has caused the problem, try opening the notebook in **jupyterlab** and delete the problamatic cell. To install jupyterlab:

```
$ pip install jupyterlab
$ jupyter lab
```

Comment: ? I am having the same issue with jupyterlab